# String index out of range (converting integer to ip)

Tags: java, string

```
    public class IPconversion {

public void integertoip(int a){


    String b = Integer.toBinaryString(a);

    int l = 32 - b.length();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String [] arr = new String[l];

    for(int k =0; k<arr.length; k++){

        arr[k] = "0";


    }

     for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
      builder.append(arr[i]);
}
        String m = builder.toString();


        b = m+b; //adds missing zeros to represent all 32 bits




     StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();
     input1.append(b);
    input1=input1.reverse(); //reverses the 32 bit binary string
    System.out.println(input1);
    String c = input1.toString();
    int len = 8; 
    String regex = "(?<=^|\\G.{" + len + "})";

    String [] parts = c.split (regex); //stores 8 bits chunks in array


    for(int i =0; i<parts.length; i++){
    StringBuilder input2 = new StringBuilder();
     input2.append(parts[i]);
    input2=input2.reverse(); //reverses the 8 bits chunks

    parts[i] = input2.toString();
    System.out.println(parts[i]);





    }



  for(int g =0; g<parts.length; g++){
      double Sum=0;
      for(int h=7; h>=0; h-- ){

          char s = parts[g].charAt(h); //error on this line
          int y = Character.getNumericValue(s);
          Sum = Sum+(Math.pow(2,7-h)*y); //computes decimal value


      }

      Double d = new Double(Sum);
      int i = d.intValue();
      System.out.println(i+".");

  }  

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    IPconversion object = new IPconversion();
    object.integertoip(167840383);


}
  }
```

So I am trying to write a code that converts a 4 byte integer into a dotted decimal(ip address), but I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error? The string has 8 characters!

Output:

```
11111110010100001000000001010000


01111111

00001010

00000001

00001010

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at ipconversion.IPconversion.integertoip(IPconversion.java:66)
    at ipconversion.IPconversion.main(IPconversion.java:86)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: are you sure that you are using this code? It seems to work for me

Comment: This code works fine just tested it

Comment: @KevinEsche yes i am using this code, but everytime i am running it it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me also. (Run under jdk8 32 & 64 bit)

You can try to check this steps:

1. Check that your project doesn't have any errors (Problems log is empty).
2. Clean project.
3. Copy paste your code to a new clean project.

There's a possibility the your compiler isn't running that code because of some environment error, maybe a build path problems. and what happens that It's running some last good build.

Edit:

I'm no Regular expression master BUT there's a wired problem. I ran your code through online compiler and I got the error.
for some reason splitting parts returns nothing.
What helps is changing the lines of code to this:

```
 String [] parts = c.split (Pattern.quote(regex)); //stores 8 bits chunks in array
```

import:  `import java.util.regex.Pattern;`

Comment: I copy pasted the code and created a new project, still gives the error!

Comment: take a look at the edit, it looks that there's some wired behavior with the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Whats your JDK version? Is it Java 8?

Comment: its JDK 7, is the version causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int g =4; g>=1; g--){ //changed this line
      double Sum=0;
      for(int h=7; h>=0; h-- ){

          char s = parts[g].charAt(h); 
          int y = Character.getNumericValue(s);
          Sum = Sum+(Math.pow(2,7-h)*y);


      }

      Double d = new Double(Sum);
      int i = d.intValue();
      System.out.print(i+".");

  }
```

So i changed the arguments of the first for loop and it works fine now. The problem was with the size of the parts array, i assumed its size to be 4, whereas its size was actually 5! and i found out that it is storing nothing at the 0th index which was actually causing the problem!